# Need help minimising cables connected to laptop using SB 3.1 gen 2 type-c with DisplayPort 1.4

Tags: usb, laptop, displayport

I have a [ROG Zephyrus G GA502DU](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07RTCXH8G/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1) and was wondering if I can somehow minimize the number of cables connected to it. Currently, I have the charger, ethernet cable, HDMI cable connected to an external monitor and other peripherals connected directly to the device.

Since the laptop has a USB 3.1 gen 2 type-c with DisplayPort 1.4, I wanted to make use of this by connecting my monitor using a standard type-c to type-c cable.

As a result, my questions are:

1) Would this even work?

2) Would it then be possible to connect a [USB hub](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Adapter-Ethernet-Delivery-MacBook-Pixelbook/dp/B07YZ4THMK/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=usb%20c%20hub%20multiport%20adapter%20with%20ethernet&qid=1590889272&sr=8-3) to the monitor which my peripherals and ethernet cable are linked to?

If this is feasible, the number of cables attached to my device would be reduced to 2 (the type-c cable and the power cable) which is why I am considering this option.

The monitor in question is the [LG UltraWide 34UC99-W](https://www.amazon.co.uk/LG-34UC99-W-Ultrawide-Adjustable-DisplayPort/dp/B072PTK61T/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2F7I981VTC93V&dchild=1&keywords=lg%2034%20ultrawide&qid=1590885884&s=computers&sprefix=lg%2034%2Ccomputers%2C140&sr=1-1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the [manual of the monitor](https://bedienungsanleitung-deutsch.de/bedienungsanleitung-handbuch/LG_34UC99_EN.pdf), it looks like it has an upstream USB-C port and two USB-C ports for peripherals (p.7).

It says that the USB-C connection is for video, audio, and extra USB data (p. 22) and that the monitor functions as an USB hub for the two additiona USB-C ports (p. 23).

So assuming your laptop also supports additional USB data on top of DisplayPort and audio (I am too lazy to also google the manual for it and verify; you can do that yourself), then yes, you can use a single type-C to type-C cable to connect your laptop to the monitor, and you can connect as many USB 3.0 hubs (or even just USB 2.0 hubs) to the monitor as you want for your other peripherals. For your ethernet cable, you'd need an USB-Ethernet adapter.

Keep in mind that if you do that, everything uses a single cable with limited bandwidth, and the video signal will take a significant part of that bandwidth already. So if you have peripherals that need a lot of bandwidth (like Ethernet), I'd recommend to connect them directly, even if it means an additional cable.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. You even answered my followup questions. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Although it might have theoretically possible, I don't have good experience with peripherals going through monitor.

An USB-C docking station / port replicator would be a more robust solution.